# Android Studioのエミュレーターがエラーになって起動出来ません。教えて下さい。

Tags: android-studio

ANGLE(D3D9)にするとクラッシュします。

エラー内容

```
Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:

gpu found. vendor id 8086 device id 0x0166

checking for bad AMD Vulkan driver version...

amdvlk64.dll not found. Checking for amdvlk32...

amdvlk32.dll not found. No bad AMD Vulkan driver versions found.

checking for vulkan-1.dll version...

info on vulkan-1.dll cannot be found, contenue.

emuglConfig_init: blacklisted=0 has_guest_renderer=1

emuglConfig_init: auto-select angle9 based on conditions and UI
prefersione 2

emuglConfig_init: Error: [Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you`re already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator. angle angle_indirect mesa swiftshader_indirect]

androidEmuglConfigInit failed.

OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (reqquires restart)" to 
 "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4.Please file an issue to https://issuetracer.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
```

と言うエラー内容です。

メーカー:FUJITSU
CPU:intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
GPU:intel HD Graphics 4000
OS:Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview 評価コピー。Bulid 19624.rs_prerelease.200502-1339

Comment: エラーメッセージにトラブルシューティングが書かれていますが試されましたか？

Comment: この記事[Android Studio, Suddenly got GPU Driver Issue when running emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45121828/9014308)の[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574323/9014308)にある、外付けGPU無し状態関連かもしれません。`ANGLE (D3D11)`, `ANGLE (D3D9)`, or `Desktop native OpenGL` のどれかに変える、ただし`これが機能することは保証されていません`らしいですね。他関連記事 [突然Androidエミュレータが起動しない](https://qiita.com/wakwak/items/701ac98fe3d887cd6976)

Comment: こちらの関係かもしれませんが。[Windows 10で「DirectX 9」が必要って言われたらどうやってインストールすればいい？](https://www.design365life.jp/0000093832/)

Comment: エラーメッセージにトラブルシューティングが書かれていますが試されましたか？ – nekketsuuu♦さん　ありがとうございます。起動出来ました

Comment: @kunif さん、その通りです。GPU無しで実行していました。